# What is the name for the dash character

Tags: pronunciation

With regard to this sentence, ...oni povas krei el ĝi 15-20 vortojn..., how would you say the dash character?

If you were reading that sentence, would you say "dek kvin **ĝis** dudek?"

Answer (score 4):

<s>Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html#i-mnc), la nomo de la signo **-** estas *dividostreko*.</s> [REDAKTO] Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html#ghis-streko), la nomo de ĉi tiu signo estas *ĝis-streko*. (Dankon, La Vo!)

Sed kiam oni elparolas „15-20“, oni diras „de 15 ĝis 20“.

Comment: I think the translation is not right. That's *hyphen* in English. Here we're looking for an *en-dash* which is [clearly distinct](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html).

Comment: Found it: [*ĝis-streko*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html#ghis-streko)

Comment: @LaVo Vi pravas! Bonvolu afiŝi ĉi tion kiel respondon. Mi forigos mian.

Comment: There's no need, that's a small thing. The question was about reading the range, not about naming the glyph.

Comment: Except that the character typed in the original question above is a hyphen, not an en-dash! In many cases nobody will notice, let alone bother about it, but if you're being careful, use a hyphen '-' only for hyphenated words, and use the longer en-dash '–' for *ĝis*.
http://www.dashhyphen.com/

Answer (score 1):

oni povas krei el ĝi **de** 15 **ĝis** 20 vortojn

Use **de** and **ĝis** when doing lower and upper bounds of a range of numbers.

<s>Additionally, these can be used for other ranges</s>
<s>e.g. I went from Paris to Berlin (Mi iris de Parizο ĝis Berlinο)</s> I have realised my mistake. **el** and **al** should be used here.

Comment: What? Is it not correct to use "de" and "gxis" for places? Where did you find that infomration?

Comment: Mi iris el Parizo al Berlino means that I went from Paris to Berlin. Mi iris de Parizo ĝis Berlino means that I went up to Berlin. Actually, accg. to Reta Vortaro, it's okay to use de-ĝis, but I didn't mean to use de-ĝis in that sentence.